# How to use point to next node when deleting elements in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have previously posted some part of this task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709450/facing-debugging-problem-when-implementing-doubly-linked-list-in-c).

I am now implementing a method that removes an element at a given index. My code is

```
void remove(int index)
    {
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            Node *current = get_node(index);
            Node *prev = get_node(index - 1);
            Node *next = get_node(index + 1);
            prev->next = current->next;
            delete current;
        }
  
   }
```

however, I am facing this error message

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
std::range_error: IndexError: Index out of range
Abort trap: 6
```

I am guessing the problem is the pointers, but I am not sure why this is not working. Anyone who can help?

Comment: Think of your boundary conditions. What if you try and remove the first element of a linked list. get_node(0 - 1). What if you try and remove the last element of a linked list (n + 1). Both of these will cause errors. Final case to think about will also be, what if it is the ONLY element in a linked list?

Comment: The function `get_node` is unknown to the reader. Your link to your other question doesn't help here. `get_node(int)`  suggests a "list" on an array that can be addressed with en index. This would inhibit to delete any single element of the array. But your old questions doesn't give any clue, there is no array and no `get_node`.  Your question doesn't show an info about `head`. I fear it's impossible to get an answer here.

Comment: DId you try to debug the code?

Comment: Traversing a linked list list three times just to locate a single node is very wasteful.

Comment: @Frebreeze I think I got some clues. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle corner cases like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
        Node(int val) {
            this->val = val;
        }
        struct Node * next;
        int val;
};


class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;    
    LinkedList() {
        head = new Node(1);
        Node * n1 = new Node(2);
        head->next = n1;
        Node * n2 = new Node(3);
        n1->next = n2;
    }
    void remove(int index) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        int pos = 0;
        Node * cur = head;
        Node *prev = NULL;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            if (pos == index) {
                break;
            }
            pos++;
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        if (prev == NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else {
            prev->next = cur->next;
        }
        delete cur;
    }
};

void print(Node * head){
    cout << "Current linked list:\n";
    while(head != NULL) {
        cout << head->val << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    LinkedList * list = new LinkedList();
    print(list->head);
    list->remove(0);
    print(list->head);
    list->remove(1);
    print(list->head);
    list->remove(0);
    print(list->head);
}
```